# How should we handle old questions and answers needing some remediation?

Tags: discussion

One comment response to a recent question (cf. [Texture shows in render but not in 3d view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35852/texture-shows-in-render-but-not-in-3d-view)) was to refer back to an earlier, similar question (cf. [Can't get my model out of wireframe mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12078/cant-get-my-model-out-of-wireframe-mode)), and when I went to review the earlier question, I found the ~.blend uploaded in response to a request, was uploaded to Pasteall, and is no longer available to download. The poster of the original question has not been active in about a year.

How should this be handled?

Comment: I'm not sure I see what's to be handled. The lack of .blend in the question doesn't affect the answer, and the OP of the new question can most likely tell if the old answer applies to their situation or not.